# incompatible types: Class<CAP#1> cannot be converted to Class<List<T>>

Tags: java, compiler-errors, incompatibletypeerror

I tried to compile a still developing project that I got it from sourceforge. this is its address:.
https://sourceforge.net/p/groove/code/5475/tree/groove/trunk/
I know that this project is well proved and it doesn't have any error but when I want to compile it, I encounter to this compile error:

```
error: incompatible types: Class<CAP#1> cannot be converted to Class<List<T>>
            this.valueType = (Class<List<T>>) new ArrayList().getClass();
where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in class SplitParser
where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
    CAP#1 extends ArrayList from capture of ? extends ArrayList
```

The error is at this file, line 370:
https://sourceforge.net/p/groove/code/5475/tree/groove/trunk/src/groove/util/parse/Parser.java
Can anyone help me about this error? I compile this program using java 8, can this be the cause of error?

**EDIT:** Interestingly project was compiled in Eclipse without error, but still has error in Netbeans with same version of java. Can anyone knows why?

Comment: Can you provide the source code you are trying to compile?

Comment: @alexander.egger Code belongs to "Groove" project on sourceforge:
https://sourceforge.net/p/groove/code/HEAD/tree/groove/trunk/src/groove/util/parse/Parser.java
Line 370

Comment: It's silly code, because it could just write `ArrayList.class`, and avoid the raw type and the unnecessary object creation. But moreover, `ArrayList.class` isn't a `Class<List>`, because it's a `Class<ArrayList>`.

Comment: Hard to tell without code!

Comment: @AndyTurner there is no difference, still not working. isn't Class<Arraylist>, also a Class<List>?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found problem. It simply about not including some needed libraries in project! I was trying to open project with Netbeans but apparently project is well configured for opening in Eclipse . So used libraries automatically imported in eclipse bot not in Netbeans. in Netbeans, it is necessary to import all used library, manually.

Comment: Please add some more helpful information into your question. Keep in mind that this question and answer should help others with the same problem

Comment: what's wrong with you @Pmpr? my explanation was enough clear!

Comment: What do you mean by "some needed libraries"? Do they have names!? Please add as much information to your answer as possible.